# Bug discount and total price PrestaShop

Tags: prestashop-1.6, price, discount

I have a PrestaShop 1.6.1.1 connected with an ERP.

Recently, we have a customer with a specific group (with -5% discount) on all products. At his last order, discount did not work ...

So, I did lot of tests. I duplicate his account then did order process and discounts works perfectly. Sometimes, when I go on product-list, discounts not showing, if I press F5 (refresh), they appear ...

- Is there anyone know where is the problem?
- Cache problem?
- If yes, how to resolve it?

Another problem, sometimes, there are price difference of 0,01€ between PrestShop and ERP or when I check order email, and when I make the sum of product prices, not the same than total.

For example, prestashop will show 237,67€ instead of 237,66€

[Screenshot of price difference here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRl9K.png)

My configuration of prestashop :

• Round mode : Round up away from zero, when it is half way there (recommended)

• Round type : Round on the total

• Number of decimals. : 2

Thanks for your replies !

Answer (score 0):

To work regularly on ERP / Prestashop laissezons, the worries of reductions can come:
- the cover
- a refreshment in the courtyard
- a hook that triggers a call in WS without conclusive answers

For the worry of rounding, this may come from the truncation method between PS and the ERP example:
Net price: 198.058333
Price includes VAT: 236.67 (incl. 20% tax)
Calculation: Price excl. VAT * 1.2 = Price incl. VAT

But with truncation at the time of import:
Price excluding VAT: 198.058333 becomes 198.05 exc. VAT
Therefore Price Tax incl.: 237.66 (VAT 20%)
Calculation: Price excl. VAT * 1.2 = Price incl. VAT

Regards

Comment: for the first reply, I dont understand ... For the second, I understand, but how  I can I solve it ? Thanks

Comment: It is necessary to check how are imported prices from the erp in Prestashop, are they rounded or truncated? And how many digits after the decimal point.